# Why I have the error Java is set to an invalid directory when i try to install Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to install Maven in order to run selenium junit test 
and then integrate it in Jenkins

When I run in CMD : `mvn -version`, I have this:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin"
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environnement to match the 
location of your Java installation.
```

When I run `java -version`, I have this:

```
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (Build 1.8.0_20-h26)
Java HotSPot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-h23, mixed mode)
```

Why do I get this error?

---

Here is my configuration for java and maven

I have Windows 7 64bits

1. I installed Maven here

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.3
   ```
2. For java, I have installed these version:

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37  should i keep this version?
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60  should i keep this version?
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11  
   C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_20  
   C:\Program Files\Java\jre6
   C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
   ```
3. In User variable, I have this:

   ```
   JAVA_HOME
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin

   MAVEN_OPTS
   %M2% 

   PATH
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin;
   ```
4. in System variable, I have this:

   ```
   JAVA_HOME
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin

   JRE_HOME
   C:\Program Files\Java\jre6;

   M2
   %MAVEN_HOME%\bin;

   MAVEN_HOME
   C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.3;

   Path
   C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin;
   ```

Comment: Capitalising "I" doesn't hurt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLease go to http://dbc-customs.com/?p=96

```
1. Download and install Java JDK (minimum 1.7) Jave SE downloads

2. Download Maven Binary from Apache from the Maven Downloads Page or use this direct link for Maven 3.2.1 (Binary zip)

3. Extract zip file to C:\Program Files (x86)\ApacheMaven\apache-maven-3.2.1 (Note: if you select a different directory, please update following steps accordingly)

4. Open the “Environment Variables” in Windows. (WinKey + Pause/Break) > Advanced System Settings > Advanced tab > “Environment Variables…” Button.

5. Add the following variables to the “System variables” section. (Not the “User variables”)

JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51

M2_HOME
C:\Program Files (x86)\ApacheMaven\apache-maven-3.2.1

M2
%M2_HOME%\bin

6. Open the “Path” variable in the System variables section, and add the following at the end of your Path:
;%M2%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
Note: the semicolon ( ; ) is used to separate values.

7. Open a new command prompt (Winkey + R then type cmd) and run mvn --version

to verify that it is correctly installed.

C:\Users\curtis>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T10:37:52-07:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files (x86)\ApacheMaven\apache-maven-3.2.1
Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Answer (score 4):

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environnement to match the 
location of your Java installation. This is clearly saying that your value to JAVA_HOME is wrong.

Change your JAVA_HOME with following value.

```
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11"
```

PATH and JAVA_HOME  are two different environment variables.
JAVA_HOME is java installation directory.
Where as PATH for Java is location of javac.exe,java.exe like executables so it is upto %JAVA_HOME%bin.

Comment: If put JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11" when i run mvn -version, it says Error: impossible to find or load the principle class C:\Program

Comment: @kirkdouglas can you post the complete error you are getting

Comment: I restarted with this configuration: M2_HOME=C:\maven\apache-maven-3.0.4 and M2=%M2_HOME%\bin and i added this in add %M2% in Path when i type mvn -version it says : Impossible to find or load the class in french Impossible de trouver ou charger la classe principale   i use windows7 64bit and with the same config with win7 32 bits it's working well

Comment: @kirkdouglas is everything fine now?

Answer (score 1):

set JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11 without the \bin
and in the path put %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: while that definitely is correct, it doesn't provide an explanation as to why you need to change the things you need to change. You could [edit] your answer to include the reasons behind that.. And... Welcome to [so] ;)

Comment: No one of above solutions is working for me, should i install maven in C:\Program Files (x86)\Maven instead of c:\Program Files?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration should be:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11
M2_HOME = C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.3
```

Then in your **PATH** add:

```
;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin
```

If you need an explanation check this:

[For Java](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/index.html)

[For Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/development/guide-building-m2.html)

Comment: This is exactly what i did, with mvn -version i got error Impossible to find or load ....

Comment: @kirkdouglas just a question, why do you say "install maven" when maven just needs to be unzipped?